# Change position of figure in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

I need to put a figure in a specific position in a `beamer` presentation ... Does it have  a solution using X and Y coordinate or another thing? What do I need to change in the following code?

```
\begin{figure}
 \hspace{4cm}  \vspace{1cm}
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,natwidth=69,natheight=87]{images/logo.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could also use the [`textpos`](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(3cm,1cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{images/logo.jpg}
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

`beamer` doesn't really support floats as they don't make sense in a presentation. The figure environment is allowed but doesn't really do much.

```
\vspace*{2cm}
\hspace*{3cm}\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,natwidth=69,natheight=87]{images/logo.jpg}
```

would probably do what you want, adjust the lengths to fit.  Leave blank lines before and after these two lines to ensure you are in vertical mode, otherwise the `\vspace` will do the wrong thing.

Comment: But then how do you add captions?

Comment: @luchonacho 99 times out of 100 images that are called "logo" and are positioned by coordinate don't need captions, but there is always the capt-of package, or you can wrap it in `figure`